# Trying to remove a value from a set which is constructed using bitvector

Tags: c, set, bit, bitarray, bitvector

Im trying to remove value from a set but can't get it to work
this is the struct

```
struct set {
int capacity;
int size;
char *array;
};
```

This is how i insert the values in to the set

```
void set_insert(const int value, set *s)
{
  if (!set_member_of(value, s))
  {
    int bit_in_array = value; // To make the code easier to read

    // Increase the capacity if necessary
    if (bit_in_array >= s->capacity)
    {
        int no_of_bytes = bit_in_array / 8 + 1;
        s->array = realloc(s->array, no_of_bytes);
        for (int i = s->capacity / 8 ; i < no_of_bytes ; i++)
        {
            s->array[i] = 0;
        }
        s->capacity = no_of_bytes * 8;
    }

    // Set the bit
    int byte_no = bit_in_array / 8;
    int bit = 7 - bit_in_array % 8;
    s->array[byte_no] = s->array[byte_no] | 1 << bit;
    s->size++;
}
```

}

This is how i've tried to remove the values. I don't know why but
it completely ruins the set and assigns different values to the
entire array

```
void set_remove(const int value, set *const s)
{
   int byte_no = value / 8;

   if(set_member_of(value, s))
   {
      s->array[byte_no] = 0;
      s->size--;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your [mcve] into the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post `set_member_of`, so I had to synthesize it.

The main issue with `set_remove` is that it is zeroing out *all* bits in the given byte. You want to *and* against the complement of the bit mask. So, change this:

```
s->array[byte_no] = 0;
```

Into:

```
s->array[byte_no] &= ~mask;
```

When I do bit masks, I like to use macros instead of shifts/divides/etc in multiple places.

In `set_insert`, I think it's easier to make `capacity` be number of *bytes* rather than number of *bits*.

Although `char` for the array type works, using `unsigned char` is probably better.

Note that as you define `set`, under C, it is *not* a type.

Anyway, here is the refactored code. I've compiled it but *not* tested it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char atom;

typedef struct set {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    atom *array;
} set;

#define INDEX(_bitno)       ((_bitno) / 8)
#define MASK(_bitno)        (7 - ((_bitno) % 8))

int
set_member_of(int bitno,set *s)
{
    int byte_no = INDEX(bitno);
    atom mask = MASK(bitno);
    atom match = 0;

    if (byte_no < s->capacity)
        match = s->array[byte_no] & mask;

    return match;
}

void
set_insert(int bitno, set *s)
{

    if (! set_member_of(bitno, s)) {
        int newcap = INDEX(bitno + 8);

        // Increase the capacity if necessary
        if (newcap > s->capacity) {
            s->array = realloc(s->array, newcap);

            // zero out any new cells
            for (int i = s->capacity;  i < newcap;  ++i)
                s->array[i] = 0;

            s->capacity = newcap;
        }

        atom mask = MASK(bitno);
        int byte_no = INDEX(bitno);
        s->array[byte_no] |= mask;
        s->size++;
    }

}

void
set_remove(int bitno, set *s)
{

    if (set_member_of(bitno, s)) {
        int byte_no = INDEX(bitno);
        atom mask = MASK(bitno);

        s->array[byte_no] &= ~mask;
        s->size--;
    }
}
```